# How to load a loading view at the end of table view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a table view in which all are customised cells which is loading from 3 types of custom cells object classes.I have done paging also so that it will load 5 pages at the begning and then the second one like that.the problem is at the end of the table view cells i need to add a loading view.For that i used `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`and added an activity indicator and loading label.but its position is not getting correctly.some times if the contents are more its position is not going correctly.Can anybody guide me the correct approach in achieving this?

Comment: how about tableFooterView?? Did you try adding a view to your tableView.tableFooterView = yourView??

Comment: i am using that ....i have returned my footerview from the methde

Comment: no.. that method is to add a footer for each section.. I gave you an idea to add as a footer view for your whole table view

Answer (score 3):

You say : "loading view at the end of table view" whereas this function :

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Will add a view at the end of a section that is different from what you want to do.

I suggest you to have a look at the following UITableView property :

tableFooterView

([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html))